# How to specify custom json file for npm run <script>

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

let's say i have my custom example.json

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "teschest": "node console.log('jf')"
    }
}
```

how do i run scripts from a custom json file other than package.json?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wonder why you would need that, and I do not think it is possible, as the package.json is the entry to npm.

Alternatively, you can use npm without the package.json, by using a makefile. you can check that here: https://mmap.page/dive-into/npm/